# How to align list element of a menu (ul menu)?

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, html-lists

I have a list menu and I display all the elements in that list thanks to

```css
.navigator ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigator li {
   margin:4px 50px -10px 0px;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   font-size:17px;
}

.navigator {
   width:100%;
   box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
   background:#3298BA;
}
```

But I want to have some elements of this list aligned to the left, others centered to the center, and the last elements to the right.

And I don't know which CSS properties I can set to get this.

This is my current menu :

[image: Menu]

And the code of this menu:

```
<nav class="navigator">
  <ul class="active">
     <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Characters</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My objective is to have Characters aligned to the `left`; Skills, Items, and Stats to the `center` and finally my account and the glyphicon aligned to the `right`

Comment: Sure, I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Comment: Use ```text-align: center;``` in your ```.navigator ul```. Then you need to make sure that your ```li``` tags are ```display: inline-block;```. To push things to the far left or right, use ```float: right;``` or ```float: left;``` on those specific elements.

Comment: What do you mean by align? If you want to spread the whole ul to fit into the nav, do the following:
give `display: table;` to nav and `display: table-row;` then, try to add some margin to each li.
Also, you might try add `table-layout: fixed;`  and add some padding to nav as well

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for each li (e.g. width: 16%) and add the following CSS

```css
.navigator li:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.navigator li:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Don't forget to set the default alignment in your `.navgator li` CSS to `center`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navigator ul
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.navigator li {
    margin:4px 10px 0px 0px;
    float:none;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:17px;
  display:inline-block;
    width: 14%;
}

.navigator {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background:#3298BA;
}
.navigator li:first-child{
text-align:left;
}
.navigator li:last-child{
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigator">
  <ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```